# How do I find the version of JQuery that is installed on a Linux web server?

Tags: shell-script, webserver

All the methods I found on the Internet involved using a .jsp page and a web browser.  I have Linux servers with no GUI desktops.

I do not want to use the web browser on a desktop to view a .jsp file on every web browser.  I want to find out from the backend.  This way I can use a script to find out on every server.

How do I find the version of JQuery that is installed on a Linux web server?

Comment: what relation JQuery has to Java Server Pages?

Comment: Most linux web servers do not host a jQuery.  Most websites use a CDN to host their jquery since it means a faster delivery (browsers limit the number of simultaneous connections to a single source)

Comment: @Serge: there is no relationship.  I am new at this.  But I did do investigation before asking.  I tried the JavaScript code in .html files too.  I guess I should not have used the .jsp extension. The .js extension was not working for my web pages.

Comment: So you want an answer from after you've SSH'ed into the box, to see what version of jquery it is serving?

Answer (score 0):

File *test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
out=$(wget -qO- $1 |
 grep -Eoi '<script [^>]+>' |  
 grep -Eo 'src="[^\"]+"' | 
 grep -Eo '["\047].*["\047]' | sed 's/\"//g')

echo -e $out | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -i "jquery"
```

Save the above commands as a shell script file.

```
bash test.sh <site_url>
```

The output will be

```
/resources/js/vendor/jquery.js
/resources/js/vendor/jquery-ui.js
/resources/js/vendor/jquery.handsontable.full.js
/resources/js/vendor/jquery.bxslider.js
```

It will print only the jquery URLs inside the  tag

Comment: This won't print "only the jquery" - it will print *anything* found in the src attribute of a html page. It also won't restrict the output to the scripts on the designated host.